# I want to run Github fie ("master>Folder>File.java") from Jenkins. How to do so?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pipeline

I want to run GitHub file ("master>Folder>File.java") from Jenkins. How to do so?

Comment: If it's on GitHub, why did you tag this [tag:bitbucket]?

Answer (score 1):

First you need the JDK version set in your Jenkins configuration, under "manage Jenkins". Then you can use [Git SCM](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) to checkout your repo that contains `File.java`. After that it's just a matter of compiling the file (with `javac`), then running it (with `java`).